# Update the dropdown contents after GET new value based on another field selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a View with 2 md autocomplete fields bind to list of values.

When I select the first field, I send a GET request to get list of values to bind to the next field.

I get the new list and update the value of my 2nd control to the new list.

But, in the UI the value contents of the 2nd list are not being updated to show the new list values.

The 2nd control is not refreshing with new values.

I have tried $scope.$apply().

But, it doesn't work. My dev tool crashes.

```js
function CompanyInfoCtrl($state, $scope, genericInfo) {
  this.states = genericInfo.states;
  this.cities = genericInfo.cities;
      
  //when user Selects a State
  //Update this.cities with the new ListOfCities in the selected State

  //Call this method where field = this.cities
  function(address, field) {
    if(address && address.state) 
      return $http.get('http://localhost:8090/common/listofcitiesbystate/' + address.state).then(function(response){
        field = response.data;
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: What's `this`? Is it `CompanyInfoCtrl` does that live in the controller?

Comment: this is CompanyInfoCtrl

Comment: If `CompanyInfoCtrl` is a controller use `$scope` instead of `this` to expose things to the view and things will be happier.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.
I did try that. But I think I would have made a mistake somewhere. I will try with $scope again.

Comment: @MaxSorin actually if he uses `contoller as` syntax `this` would work just fine, he doesn't need the `$scope`

Comment: Hey, not sure why. But simple assignment(=) in AngularJS was not setting it to Dirty State. I had to Pop() all the elements from the Array and Push(newElements) the elements from the new Array List.  This, however, does set it to dirty state triggering a refresh/render of the new list. Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 0):

The model was not being set to Dirty state and hence it was not refreshing with the new values.

In my code, I was previously setting the new value as:-

```
//where UiElementArrayList is a list of object and is bind to md autocomplete
//I need to update the list with new valueList based on User Action/Selection
//GET call to fetch new data
    this.cities =  response.data
```

This solved the problem:-

```
//1. Empty the array
//2. Push the elements from the Response array to the UiElementArrayList
//i.e.
while(this.cities.length > 0)
    this.cities.pop()
for(i=0; i < response.data.length; i++)
    this.cities.push(response.data[i])
```

And this sets the model to dirty state and does a refresh and I could see the new List elements. :)

Please do suggest any Improvements/Better ways for this if you encounter the same problem.